# How to make the animation done by google when we search for anything from the Home page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am asking for the following thing...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tsMd.png)

when we type anything in the searchbox...

You can see that when we type anything in the textbox in homepage..it automatically converts as header.

Please tell me the code using css,html and javascript(no jquery please..i dont know)

Comment: What code have you tried? What issue have you found when coding?

Comment: You installed 360? why? I don't know what do you mean 'converts as header', you mean searching suggestions or display results instantly?

Comment: _(no jquery please..i dont know)_... then why the tag?

Comment: @Sarath http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

To change current window title (current tab text) you can use this JS code:

```
document.title = 'Hallo Varold!';
```